# Is there a way to know the type of protocol used by the BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) scanned device in Xamarin?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making an application that scans the nearby BLE devices in Xamarin, using the Bluetooth LE plugin library. I would like to know how I can find out what type of protocol the scanned device uses so that I can differentiate between iBeacon, Eddystone, etc.

I have seen applications that are capable of doing this like Beacon Simulator or BLE Scanner.

[Beacon Simulator scan result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltKZt.png)

To scan devices I use this function, similar to the one explained in Bluetooth LE plugin for Xamarin documentation.

```
    async void ScanDevices()
    {
        if (Ble.State == BluetoothState.On)
        {
            if (!Adapter.IsScanning)
            {
                deviceList.Clear();//clear list
                Adapter.ScanTimeout = Constants.Scann_time_ms;
                Adapter.ScanMode = ScanMode.Balanced;
                Adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
                {
                    //scan and search for devices
                    if (!deviceList.Contains(a.Device))
                    {                          
                            deviceList.Add(a.Device);
                    }

                };

                id_devicesCollection.ItemsSource = deviceList;

                await Adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[INFO] Scanned");

            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[WARNING] device is scaning");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[WARNING] BLE State is OFF ");
        }
    }
```

Could I get the information I'm looking for from <Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.AdvertisementRecord> by interpreting raw data?

Comment: You use the service uuid in the advertisement data.

Comment: IBeacons will never show up in a Bluetooth scan on iOS. You need to connect to peripherals and retrieve their services to identify them